# Which DSLRs can be used with Minolta Auto Bellows I?

Tags: dslr, adapter, bellows

Will a DSLR camera body mate with the Minolta Auto Bellows I? Which DSLR will work, if any?
To clarify, I'm a novice. I've posted a photo with a black round bar projecting out of the bottom of the lens mount on a Minolta Auto Bellows I. Doesn't this bar have to engage something mechanically within the camera body in order for the bellows to work? Does a DSLR have a means to engage this bar? TIA Don

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The Minolta Auto Bellows I has a [Minolta SR mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minolta_SR-mount).  This mount is often referred to by its last revision, MD.  The bellows can be used with any camera that has an MD adapter.  These include  Canon EF, Nikon F, Pentax K, Sony A, and nearly all mirrorless mounts.  (Search your favorite shopping sites for adapters.)

If your adapter has glass elements, remove them.  Normally, they are used to compensate for incompatible [FFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flange_focal_distance), but it is not necessary when using bellows.

Comment: Yes, I use my Minolta MD Bellows with my EOS DSRL. It is a little cumbersome, because you need to focus wide open, and then stop down to take the picture. The aperture coupling will not usually work.

Comment: You want to use a thin adapter, which will probably not have any electronics in it. So, you camera won't think that there is a lens attached. A few low-end cameras will not fire the shutter without a lens. Some others need to have an option set to allow them to shoot without a lens.