# Removing Glass from an Adaptor

Tags: lens-mount, bellows

I asked earlier about mounting a DSLR to a Minolta Auto Bellows I. Someone suggested a lens adaptor and also suggested that if it came with a glass element to remove the glass. How do I remove this glass? TIA Don

[image: Adaptor]

Comment: What camera body are you planning on using?

Comment: A link to your [earlier question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/128990/15871) would save time for those who might want to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be simpler to purchase an MD/MC adapter without a glass element in it, specifically for macro use, like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VD87KKK).

Comment: How do you know that the OP wants to mount this on an EF-mount camera?

Comment: @osullic I don't, hence the words "**like** this one" not "this one". :) But assuming Canon EF is mostly just [playing the odds](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1004962/global-leading-manufacturers-digital-cameras-market-share-sales-volume/#:~:text=Canon%20dominated%20the%20global%20digital,percent%20of%20the%20market%2C%20respectively.).